# Why is there no "new" keyword in this example of instantiating a class?

Tags: java, class, instantiation

I am learning Java. To instantiate a class we use the `new` keyword, but I don't understand what this line of code means. Why there is no `new` keyword here?

```
AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
                                      AppDatabase.class,
                                      "database_transaction").build();
```

Comment: You don't always need `new` to get an instance of a class.

Comment: `new` creates a new instance; `method(....)` calls that method which, in this case, returns an instance (maybe created inside that method) - the name `databaseBuilder` is an indication that a new instance is builded

Comment: If you dive inside the build method, you will find the `new` keyword.

Comment: *You* aren't instantiating the class here.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger , yes after reading abstract factory method i now understand that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask about this:

```
AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
                                      ppDatabase.class,
                                      "database_transaction").build();
```

This is a call to a method (the static method `databaseBuilder` on a `Room` class) followed by a second call to a `build()` method on the object returned by the first call.  The second call is then returning an `AppDatabase` object.

Somewhere inside one of those methods, I *expect* that `new` is being used to explicitly create a new object<sup>1</sup>.

This looks like an example of a general pattern called the [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern where the logic of creating objects is encapsulated in a static method or an instance method.  More specifically, this looks like the [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern.

It is worth reading those two links to understand the advantages and drawbacks of those patterns.  They can also be combined with the [Fluent Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) API design pattern to reduce the number of parameters and/or method overloads.

---

<sup>1 - I could be wrong.  It is possible to create objects in other ways; e.g. by boxing, by deserializing an object serialization stream or by using `Unsafe` or native code methods.  It is also possible that the names of the methods are misleading and `build()` is returning a pre-existing object.</sup>

Comment: Thanks i understand now